# Linker error with empty braces initialization

Tags: c++, gcc, linker-errors

The following code compiles normally:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Config {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> info;
};

void f(const Config& = Config()) { }

int main() {
    f();
}
```

however, the following seems to produce a linker error on some compilers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Config {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> info;
};

void f(const Config& = {}) { }

int main() {
    f();
}
```

On GCC on CentOS 7 (`c++ (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)`), it produces the following linker error:

```
/tmp/ccM1NXXc.o: In function `main':
test.cc:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > >::map()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

On other platforms/compiler versions, it seems to work fine. Is this a compiler bug, and should the two codes work the same? (Should `= {}` initialization of `Config` result in default-construction of the `std::map`?)

Comment: What compilation/linker flags did you use?

Comment: Isn't this caused because your function accepts a reference to your Config object? Initialising it with braces won't create a reference AFAIK

Comment: only the basic `c++ test.cc -o test` command

Comment: It should create a reference to a temporary default-constructed `Config`, that exists until the end of the `f()` call

Comment: It's likely a bug in version 7.3. [I can replicate it in 7.3 but not 7.4](https://godbolt.org/z/hBhCVJ).